# Setting default select value for kendo multiselect if dataSource has only one item

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I have a Kendo multiselect with a dataBound event, that evaluates the number of items in DataSource. If the value is 1 I want it to set that item to selected. I managed to do this for combobox but with multiselect it doesn't recognize the select function (this.select(0)).

This is the event function, which worked for combobox:

```
 function onDataBound() {
      var ds = this.dataSource.data();
      if (ds.length == 1) {
       this.select(0);
      }
  }
```

I couldn't find any documentation as to how this should be done.